# Springboot data User relationship setup

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to know how to setup the following relationship:

The relationship relates to Users (Entity) where each user can come from one of multiple Organisations. The second entity is for recording the organisation specific details (Entity) of each user.

Each organisation has its own entity.

```
@Entity
public class User

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long Id
private Name name
```

Then I have several entities for each organisation. Each user needs to have exactly one mapping to one record in one of these entities:

```
@Entity
public class EducationUserDetails

@Id
private Long Id
@MapsId
private User user;
private String teacherRegistrationNo
private String teacherSchool


@Entity
public class DoctorUserDetails

@Id
private Long Id
@MapsId
private User user;
private String medicalCouncilNo
private String doctorHospital
```

How do I setup/model this relationship?

Comment: Don't know the mapping associations still, please clarify.

Comment: Each User has one record on one of the organisation details.

Comment: In terms of what i am trying to do. I have users from various organisations, but no matter what organisation a user comes from certain fields are common, ie every user no matter where they are from have a username, email, surname, firstname. Then depending on organsation there are certain other fields to be captured, like doctor registration or teacherschool etc.

Answer (score 0):

See the [MapsId documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html). It requires a `@ManyToOne` or `@OneToOne` relationship.

If you want to have a one-to-one mapping using the same primary key then you can use `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`.

```
   @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn  
   @OneToOne 
   private User user;
```

Example see: https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-annotation/

Comment: I don't understand how for a user who teacher for example it will know there is a relationship to the education table (as opposed to any of the other organisation tables) - unless on user there is a organisation attribute and then some if logic in the backend?

Comment: I have been following Vlads blogs here https://vladmihalcea.com/2016/07/26/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/ but this is not pure one to one as its more like a sometimes one to one.

Comment: so you wanna have always a one-to-one mapping between user and education? for better understanding it would be helpfull to have a entity diagram which also show bi- and unidirectional bindings. you can always define a one-to-one mapping from user to education. at the moment i don't understand with what problem you struggle. best you could provide what you already have and descrive wgat doesn't work